# Obtaining YouTube video ID from URL

Tags: android-youtube-api

I'm using YouTube's Android Player API to play YouTube videos in an app I'm developing. A video's ID must be supplied to the API to load a video, but in this situation I'm trying to play a video given it's URL. Plenty of SO questions suggest ways of using regex to obtain the video ID from a URL, but that seems temperamental, and the YouTube developer policies say developers can't "...use any technology other than YouTube API Services to access or retrieve API Data, including to access any portion of any YouTube audiovisual content", which seems to indicate that this is not the intended way to load videos.

Is there a recommended way of using YouTube's API's to obtain a video ID from its URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo");

        if (matcher.find()) {
            String id = matcher.group();
            Log.i("id", "++++" + id);
        }
```

Hope it helps you.!!